# Passing an instance of a functor to another functor

Tags: c++, functor

For structural reasons, I'd like to be able to pass an instance of a functor to another functor. At the moment I achieve something equivalent by handing a pointer to a function to my functor.

I've attempted to encapsulate the idea in some minimal code below:

```
class A
{
private:
    double _x, _y, _z;

public:
    A (double x, double y, double z) : _x(x), _y(y), _z(z) {};

    void operator() (double t) const
    {
        // Some stuff in here that uses _x, _y, _z, and t.
    }
};

class B
{
private:
    // What is the type of the functor instance?
    ??? A ???

public:
    // How do I pass the instance of A into B at initialisation?
    B (??? A ???) :  ??? : {};

    void operator() (double tau) const
    {
        // Something that uses an instance of A and tau.
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    // I want to do something like this:
    A Ainst(1.1, 2.2, 3.3); // Instance of A.
    B Binst(Ainst);         // Instance of B using instance of A.

    Binst(1.0);             // Use the instance of B.

    return 0
}
```

In essence, I want to be able to chain up functors. As stated above, I currently do this by passing a function pointer to B along with variables x, y, and z. In my code B is templated and the goal is to write it once and then reuse it without any modification later, which means that handing x, y, and z to B is not ideal. A on the other hand will be customised for each program that I write. I don't mind B being quite messy, but I want A to be nice and clean as this is the part that will be exposed.

For those who know some quantum mechanics, B is the Schrödinger equation (or a master equation) and A is a time dependent Hamiltonian. The variables x, y, and z are used to construct the Hamiltonian, and t is time, allowing me to use the [odeint](http://headmyshoulder.github.com/odeint-v2/) library (so I'm using ublas and a couple of other Boost bits).

Comment: You need std::bind. It can chains functors, and bind parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using references?

```
class A { /* ... */ };

class B
{
    A &a;

public:
    B(const A &my_a)
        : a(my_a)
    { }

    // ...
};
```

Comment: Amazing. Very embarrassing that I didn't think of this first. Regardless, you've saved me several hours of pounding my head against a macbook keyboard and I'm very *very* thankful. Thanks!